# Identify Amazon EC2 machines uniquely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Consider I have installed a software in an Amazon EC2 machine, activated it successfully. Now I make this as an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) and then launch multiple instances.

How can the software identify that this is not the original machine where the product was activated?

Usually we use Hard disk, RAM and other hardware details to identify activation and then enabled the Software, but I am not sure how to proceed with Amazon images.

Answer (score 1):

Each Amazon EC2 instance has an `InstanceId` in the form `i-0c9c9b24b3583afdc`.

These IDs are unique and are not reused.

For example, the cloud-init process that runs a User Data script no first boot uses this technique to determine when to run the script. It checks whether the script has run for the given Instance ID. If it has, then the script is not run again. If an AMI is made of the instance and a new instance is launched from the AMI, it notices that the Instance ID has changed and the script runs. So, it actually runs "once per Instance ID".

Comment: I am reading more on Instance Id and how to get this value, is there any way to figure if it is a physical machine or amazon cloud machine at machine level properties? I wanted to add condition before I made a call to '169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data'

Comment: Well, a non-Amazon EC2 instance won't give back anything on 169.254.169.254.